# Quasi-isometric embedding of graphs in non-compact riemannian surfaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a complete riemannian surface $(S,m)$, where $S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, I would like to find a weighted graph $G$ (which means a graph with real non-negative weights on the edges), embedded in $S$, and such that the (weighted) shortest path metric in $G$ is quasi-isometric to $m$ (this means that there are constants $\lambda,\epsilon,C$ such that for any vertices $x,y$ in $G$, $\tfrac1\lambda d_G(x,y)-\epsilon \le d_m(f(x),f(y)) \le \lambda d_G(x,y)+\epsilon$, where $f$ denotes the embedding of $G$ in $S$, and every point of $S$ is at distance at most $C$ from some vertex of $G$).

Note that in particular $G$ will be planar. I need that in addition, $G$ is countable and locally finite (meaning that any bounded region of $S$ contains only a finite number of vertices of $G$).

I have seen such statements proved for compact surfaces (in this case $G$ can be taken to be finite), or non-compact surfaces with some uniform bounds on the curvature or strong convexity radius (in both cases the vertex set is just an $\epsilon$-net on the surface, for a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$), but I suspect the result holds in much greater generality.

I am not an expert in riemannian geometry and I lack some background in the area. Have you seen such a statement proved in a clean way in an article or a textbook? Thank you in advance!

Comment: For $\lambda =1$ and $m$ Euclidean this is an open problem (by Bruce Kleiner). If $\lambda$ can be arbitrary the question should not be too difficult.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reference. What suprises me is that I have only seen mentions of this result (with arbitrary $\lambda$) or explicit proofs in fairly specific cases (compact surfaces for instance). If it holds in greater generality it should certainly appear somewhere in the literature.

Comment: It's amusing that "weight" is used in a sense that would intuitively be a length...

Comment: Consider the ordinary square lattice on the plane. Assign wait $w$ for every edge $(x,y):  w(x,y)=m(x,y)$ where $x,y$ are adjacent vertices. You get a weighted square lattice on the plane. Isn't this embedding a quasi-isometry with $\lambda=2$?

Comment: Of course number 2 in my previous comment can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I might get things wrong in your comment, but how do you make sure that each point on the surface is close from the square lattice? For any fixed size of square, your surface might be arbitrarily wild inside some square face (with points that are arbitrarily far from the boundary of their face), right? In the quasi-isometry the image has to be a net, i.e. each point of the surface has to be close from a vertex (or edge, that's equivalent) of $G$.

Comment: Also, a path following the edges of the grid could be arbitrarily bad compared to a path crossing the faces, no?

Comment: A surface cannot be arbitrarily wild inside a square because $m$ is smooth? If it can be wild, my idea won't work. The result could be in some paper by Kleiner. You may ask him directly. It is certainly his topic.

Comment: What is the construction when $\lambda=1$ and $S$ is isometric to $R^2$? Is there a good reference or a simple description? An ordinary square grid does not have good approximations to diagonal lines.

Comment: @MarkSapir the surface is smooth, but close to be euclidean possibly only on small neighborhoods (and the radius of these neighborhoods can tend to 0 as we go to infinity, since the surface is not compact), so you cannot fix the size of your square grid globally, your graph has to be defined more locally on the surface.

Comment: @MattF. Here is a good reference for the Euclidean case: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.2435.pdf

Comment: @Arnaud, thanks! That clearly answers my question, it's just a pity there are no pictures.

Comment: Take a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0812/0812.0456v1.pdf) by Saucan and Katchalsky; maybe it contains the result you need or you can use the proof...

Comment: That's extremely helpful, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the usual "economic covering" method: By Zorn (but alternatively, you can easily do it with your bare hands without using the choice axiom), $S$ admits a maximal family $(x_i)$ of 1-separated points (meaning that the distance between $x_i$ and $x_j$ is at least 1 for $i\neq j$). Then, the balls $B_i$ of center $x_i$ and radius $2$ cover $S$; but consider rather the covering by the larger balls $B'_i$ of center $x_i$ and radius $5/2$. Clearly, every geodesic segment in $S$ of length $\le 1$ lies in a ball $B'_i$.
Let $G_0$ be the $1$-skeleton of this covering $(B'_i)$: its vertices are the $x_i$'s; its edges are the pairs $(x_i,x_j)$ s.t. $B'_i$ intersects $B'_j$. Put the weight $1$ on each edge. By choosing a shortest geodesic between $x_i$ and $x_j$ for each edge, you get a map $f:G_0\to S$ which is clearly a quasi-isometry (indeed, given any shortest geodesic $\gamma$ on $S$ of length $\le n$, cut it into $n$ segments $[y_k,y_{k+1}]$ of length $\le 1$; one has a vertex $v_{i_k}$
of $G_0$ at distance $\le 2$ from each point $y_k$; by the triangle inequality, $B'_{i_k}$ and
$B'_{i_{k+1}}$ intersect; hence $\gamma$ lies at Hausdorff distance $2$ of a simplicial path in $G_0$ of length $\le n$). Of course, $f$ is not an embedding in general; however it is locally finite (any compact subset of $S$ meets only finitely many edges); in particular, once you have added the intersections of the edges as new vertices, you get an embedded, locally finite, quasi-isometric graph $G$.

(Of course, the nature of the problem changes if one adds the extra requirement that $\lambda=1$; which I do not ).

Comment: This does not solve the problem: in $R^2$, consider the family of points $1.1\mathbb{Z}\times 1.1\mathbb{Z}$, which is maximal. Then the suggested $G_0$ will not have any $\lambda=1$ approximations to long line segments with slopes like 1/3, violating one of the conditions of the problem. E.g. a segment of the line $y=x/3$ might be approximated by sequences of three horizontal edges and one vertical edge, but that approximation multiplies the length by $4/\sqrt{10} > 1$.

Comment: I'm happy with any constant $\lambda$, so I'm accepting this solution. Thank you very much! I completely missed the idea of replacing edge crossings by vertices, that's much simpler than what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Can you choose G so that its face-boundaries have uniformly bounded lengths? (Equivalently, so that every face of G is bounded by a triangle).

Perhaps you can fiddle around a little to get rid of intersections too close to the x_i, so that your edges have lengths bounded below. Thus, for a different λ, you could let all edges of G have length 1.